# Magento2 API update multiple inventory items

Tags: api, rest, soap, inventory, magento2

I'm developing integration with magento. My client want to update his inventory via REST or API, the problem is that he has thousands of products and it will take a lot of time to update them one by one. I didn't found the way to update many inventory items neither from SOAP nor from REST. (For previous versions i used catalogInventoryStockItemMultiUpdate)

How to update a lot of inventory items in 1 call?